# How to set second parameter for attr method?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a jquery code as below

```js
$(document).on('click', '.ajax', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var getUrl = $(this).attr('href');
    var myData = $(this).data();
    var data = new FormData();
    for (var i in myData) {
        data.append((i.replace("record", "")), myData[i]);

    }

    reModal(getUrl, data);
});
```

and I want to change/update this line:

```
 var getUrl = $(this).attr('href');
```

this line must work both `href` and `data-href` not only with `href` and I want to do that.. is that possible ?

```
<a href="files_path/bla.html" class="ajax">click me</a>
```

-

```
<div data-href="files_path/yeap.html" class="ajax">click me too</a>
```

Comment: `$(this).attr('data-href')` why not?

Comment: I see more than one attr("href"); in anchor and div but href parameter is not valid in div that's why I have to manipulate with jquery instead of change all href with data-href

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass regular expression with `attr` names. So either you have to check which `attr` present for the element and pick that.

Something like this

```
 var getUrl = $(this).attr('href') ? $(this).attr('href') : $(this).attr('data-href');
```

or even shorter

```
var getUrl = $(this).attr('href') || $(this).attr('data-href');
```

Comment: great works! thank you bu is that short of if condition ?

Comment: Yes called as ternary operator.

Comment: A more concise way to write this would be `var getUrl = $(this).attr('href') || $(this).attr('data-href');`

Answer (score 1):

attr's second parameter must be something that evaluates to a value, that will be set to the parameter.

If you want to set both attribute, you can chain the methods, like this:

```
$(this).attr('href','one').attr('data-href','another');
```

If you want both, just query them individually, for example into an array:

```
var getUrl = [$(this).attr('href'),$(this).attr('data-href')];
```

When one of the attributes can have NULL value and they have some kind of priority, you can use the `||` operator, to get the first non-null value:

```
var getUrl = $(this).attr('href') || $(this).attr('data-href');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get second attribute by passing it to the data like:

```
var getUrl = $(this).attr('href') ? $(this).attr('href') : $(this).data('href');
```

Like if you want to access `href`
Use :

```
var href = $(this).attr('href');
```

And For `data-href`
You can use:

```
var href = $(this).attr('data-href');

OR

var href = $(this).data('href');
```